# Why "—" is converted into "?" from XML into HTML?

Tags: html, xml, apache, xslt, special-characters

I have created a web app on top of elasticsearch using Servlet and Tomcat. I am using Saxon to convert XML into HTML web page using XSL stylesheet.

I am not sure why the '—' in my XML is converted into a "?" in my HTML.

This is the part of my XML(the title field)

```
<T>Director Brennan Speaks at the Council on Foreign Relations — Central Intelligence Agency</T>
```

This XML is converted into HTML. This is how the title looks like in my webapp
[image]

You will observe the ?(question mark in the title).

I am not sure why this is happening. I am using encoding "UTF-8" in my XSL. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your xml after the transformation? Does it look broke? I doubt you will get any good answers, cause nobody can reproduce your problem. For a solution in XSLT you might have to post a reproduceable, minified example where your problem still occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's almost certainly a character encoding issue of some kind.

First thing to do is to check the encoding of the character in the XML. What is the actual binary/hex code used to represent the character in the XML file? (You'll need some tool that displays the file in hex to find out. Be careful to avoid copying the file in a way that might change the encoding.) Then check that the actual encoding is consistent with the declared encoding, that is, the encoding that appears in the XML declaration at the head of the file, assuming there is one.

If that all looks correct you need to do the same for the HTML file. Again, look at the HTML file in a hex editor and beware of copying it in a way that might change the encoding. If the HTML file is incorrect internally, you then need to study all the transformation steps that could have corrupted the character. If however the HTML file is correct, you need to look at the steps you were using to view the HTML (e.g. serving it from a web server to a browser.)

I think the two most likely causes are (a) the declared encoding of the XML file doesn't match the actual internal encoding, or (b) you're viewing the HTML file in a browser and the HTTP headers or Charset parameters cause it to be displayed with the wrong encoding (or rather, decoding).

One thing that definitely doesn't affect it is the encoding of the XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. This was helpful. I will try to check the transformation steps again.